# Full Rackspace cloud server backup to local

Tags: server, backup, disk, cloud, rsync

I want to rsync my entire Rackspace cloud server disk to a local drive. The command I am currently using is:

```
rsync --dry-run --archive --xattrs --compress --partial --progress --exclude={/proc/*,/sys/*,/tmp/*,/run/*,/mnt/*,/media/*,/lost+found} / user@remote_server:/backup_dir
```

I figure I should not exclude `/dev/` because my root partition is on `/dev/xvda1`.

However, when I run this, I get no output and it exits immediately. The exit code (checked with `echo $?`) is `0`. What could be going on?

Also: if there is a better way to do this, or more appropriate command line flags, do tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `--verbose` option? Hopefully this will make rsync tell you something about what's going on.

**Side note:** If it were me, I wouldn't be backing up the whole of `/`. Even with the exclusions you've listed, you'll still be backing up a lot of (pretty large) files that don't need backing up, like `/usr` and `/bin`. It's probably easier to sync just the directories you do need rather than excluding than the ones you don't.